# Push notification или оптимизированная проверка новых сообщений

Tags: html, websocket, html5, javascript

Приветствую всех.

Я реализовал чат на сокетах, все работает, как подобает, но хочется заранее оптимизировать сией процесс.

На данный момент скрипт работает следующим образом:

Пользователь входит в чат, браузер отправляет запрос через сокеты (HTML5), и запрос улетает на сервер и обрабатывается в цикле, каждая итерация - обращение в БД (цикл засыпает на полсекунды), то есть если клиент будет находится в чате 10 минут, то это, грубо говоря, 1200 обращений в БД.

Как можно оптимизировать процесс?

У меня следующее соображение:

Создать отдельный файл, при каждой записи в БД записывать в этот файл ID через функцию `file_put_contents()` и уже проверять о поступивших данных не в БД, а в файле, и если эти данные новые, то уже доставать их из БД. Но какие могут крыться подводные камни при таком подходе? И вообще правильно ли так делать или же это совсем уж криво? Может быть, имеются другие варианты решение проблемы? Я впервые столкнулся с подобной задачей.